# Angular 4 navigation using ui-router

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, router

I am upgrading to angular 4.  I am currently using ui-router with states for navigation.  I have a mix of angular 1.x and all new development is in angular 4.    I was hoping that i could map new routes to old using RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: true, enableTracing: true})

How can I navigate from a new angular 4 component to an old angular 1.x page?

Comment: Let me make the question a little more clear...  The application is currently written using angular 1.x.  The top frame and the left navigation bar are all 1.x.  The inside view window is a mix of angular 4 and 1.x components.  I would like to navigate the main window back to a 1.x view which is not a component.  How can the angular 4 component (inside the main window) navigate to a ui-router state?

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called `ngUpgrade` that is built for this purpose.

You can find out more about it here:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html

and here

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/10/24/upgrading-apps-to-angular-2-using-ngupgrade.html

Comment: 1.x navigation used: <a ui-sref="{{::menu[0].action}}" ...>  new 4.x navigation uses <a [routerLink]="menu[0].action"...>

Comment: I am currently using ngUpgrade...  I have a mix of 1.x and 4.x.  I am asking how a 4.x component can change the route to a 1.x component view.  My 4.x component is currently in a 1.x view.